Domain is not registered on TinyMCE customer portal
I'm facing the following isse. In my azurewebsite CMS I getting the following message when trying to edit a page:
**
"This domain i not registered in the TinyMCE Customer Portal. Please alert the admin to add it to approved domains to continue using TinyMCE" **
The problem is that my organisation nevr registered in TinyMCE. So then I went ahead and open an account and registered our CMS domain. That didn't help. I'm still getting the same message.
Any help/hint will appreaciated
error from TinyMCE on editor page in my azurewebsite CMS
So then I went ahead and open an account and registered our CMS domain. That didn't help. I'm still getting the same message.
